# What is needed to run "npm run build"?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vuetify.js, npm-install

What is needed to run `npm run build`?

I have project vue

I want to install it to a new server

Do I only need to run `npm install`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually `npm run build` will create a production build.

The build process does a lot of things for you:

- transpiles JS code
- bundles code and assets
- uses cache busting techniques for assets
- removes dead code

Using the production build is the way to go for production.

Later edit:

You should install `npm` to be able to run `npm` commands. You should also run `npm install` before running `npm run build`.

Comment: What is needed to run `npm run build`? I tried `npm install`, but it does not work as I asked above

Comment: This is a new server. Do I need to install node js?

Comment: You should do the build on your own machine and then just deploy the compiled files. If you want to do the build on that machine, then yes, you need to install node/npm and then run npm install/npm run build

Comment: It seems that if I install the node, I don't need to install npm. because it's already 1 package

Comment: If I just need to `npm run build`, actually I don't need to run `npm install`. Right?

Comment: You need to run npm install, because you're using other packages that aren't available until you run install.

Comment: My project use vue version 3.11.0. If I install new version of node(version 13) in my server. Is that okay?

Answer (score 1):

you need package.json that contains :

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  }
```

and also must contains dependencies like this

```
 "dependencies": {
    "style-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vuex": "^3.3.0"
  },
```